# Proof of convergence of a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is in quotation marks:

"For every $y$ $\in$ $\mathbb R^n$ and some particular sequence {$x_k$}$_{k\in\mathbb N}$, the sequence ||$x_k + y$|| converges.  Prove that the sequence {$x_k$}$_{k\in\mathbb N}$ converges."

Now, I was thinking of showing that ||$x_k + y$|| convergence $\implies$ $x_k + y$ convergence.  However, I don't think this is necessarily true.  As for a proof using the definition of Cauchy, I have:

||$x_n - x_m$|| = ||$x_n + y -(x_m + y)$| |

However, the Reverse Triangle Inequality does **not** permit me to say that

||$x_n + y -(x_m + y)$||  ≤ ||$x_n + y$|| - ||$x_m + y$|| < $\epsilon$ for $n,m$ sufficiently large

Any suggestions?

Comment: The norm is probably the Euclidean norm, $\lVert x\rVert = \sqrt{\sum x_k^2}$? The convergence of $\lVert x_k - y\rVert$ gives you the distance (of the putative limit) from $y$. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, can you choose a few points $y_i$, such that the distances from a point $p$ to all the $y_i$ determine the location of $p$?

Comment: The triangle inequality you want is just $\|a-b\| \le \|a\| + \|b\|$.

Comment: Yes, the Euclidean norm.  So a proof in R^2 would be sufficient?

Comment: Higher dimensions wouldn't change the principle. It would involve more coordinates, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This holds true for any norm.  First, let $y=0$ to deduce that the sequence is bounded.  This allows you to deduce the existence of a convergent subsequence.  Let $x$ denote the limit of the subsequence.  By hypothesis, $\|x_k-x\|$ converges.  But we know that a subsequence of this sequence of norms converges to zero, so the whole sequence must.